# Test whether calling a function locks current thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, tdd

I am writing an application that sends some command to serial port and receive some respond from it. At some point when some command is sent to port calling thread shall be locked until some respond is received. So I tried to write a failing test for it.

The problem is the test shall not finish at any time in order to be passed!!!!!

so what is the solution?

EDIT:
I can create another thread in my test and after waiting for example two seconds check that the thread is not finished, but it breaks the laws of simplicity and make tests timely.

Comment: Why is your unit blocking at all? You should be able to inject the blocking code and force it to block / not block at will (along with timeout for unblocking). I think you have not injected all your dependencies.

Comment: @Tejs what I get from your comment is that I can create another class that handles the locking. So when I want the function to block I can use that class. also I can mock that class in my unit test and inject it. Thanks.

Comment: How are you going to handle the race conditions?  That is, what if the code reading from the serial port *finishes* before the test to see if the lock is taken runs?  Or what if the code reading from the serial port *does not start until after* the test to see if the lock is taken runs?

Comment: @EricLippert I've wrapped the serial port, so I can produce the correct situation at test time. At run time the respond is always created after sending of the command. so after sending thread is locked, and new data is received on serial port, some event on another thread is dispatched which unblocks the sender thread. Also no new command can be sent until the respond for the older command is received which required another lock.

Comment: In that case why don't you simply call the overload of Monitor.TryEnter that takes a ref bool?  It immediately returns and the bool tells you whether or not the lock was taken.  (Don't forget to release the lock if it was.)

Comment: @EricLippert I'm not experienced in TDD.I think in that case my test become dependent on the implementation of the production code.

Comment: @mehdi.loa: Well then what is this question asking for?

Comment: @EricLippert I've inferred the answer by Tejs comment!

Comment: I was trying to find a way to check that my written function is blocked until some new respond is received.

Answer (score 1):

Try to get the lock for a period of time which you think its unreasonable, after which you stop trying to get the lock and fail it?

Use something like [Monitor.TryEnter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.tryenter.aspx)

Comment: It is a solution but it makes the tests timely. also using the Monitor.TryEnter makes the test dependent on the production code.